# Why doesn't `first` from Data.Bifunctor transform this value

Tags: haskell, bifunctor

In the following:

```
import Data.Bifunctor
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8 as BLU

safeReadFile :: FilePath -> ExceptT Text IO Text
safeReadFile p = (lift $ doesFileExist p) >>= bool (throwError "File does not exist") (lift $ pack <$> readFile p)

safeDecodeJSONFile :: FromJSON a => Text -> FilePath -> ExceptT Text IO a
safeDecodeJSONFile t f = do
  contents <- safeReadFile f
  tryRight $ first (\x -> pack (x ++ (unpack t))) (eitherDecode (BLU.fromString (unpack contents)))
```

When I run `runExceptT $ safeDecodeJSONFile "something" "nonExistantFile.json"` I expect to  get `Left "Does not exist something"` but instead I just get `Left "Does not exist"` - I know that the function I pass to `first` is being executed, since without the `pack` GHC complains that the type of `(eitherDecode (BLU.fromString (unpack contents)))` is `ExceptT String IO a` instead of `ExceptT Text IO a` - so why doesn't the concatenation from `++` also happen?

Comment: Just because it type checks doesn't mean it's executed. `safeReadFile f` is probably returning an error value and short-circuiting the computation.

Comment: Yeah... you're right. In hindsight that's obvious. Post it as an answer and I'll be happy to accept it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written

```
safeDecodeJSONFile t f = do
  contents <- safeReadFile f
  tryRight $ ...
```

The `Monad` instance for `ExceptT` gives up as soon as it hits `Left`, returning exactly that. So the `tryRight ...` never happens. You need to handle the `Left` case explicitly, perhaps using `catchError`.

While we're at it, there's still a problem. You write

```
safeReadFile :: FilePath -> ExceptT Text IO Text
safeReadFile p = (lift $ doesFileExist p) >>= bool (throwError "File does not exist") (lift $ pack <$> readFile p)
```

Unfortunately, this isn't reliable. First off, the file not existing is only *one* reason reading it can fail--there could be permission errors, network problems for networked filesystems, device errors if the file isn't a regular file, etc. Second, someone else could *delete* the file between the time you check its existence and the time you try to read it. The usual advice when trying to deal with files is *not* to check first. Just read the file and catch any exceptions using `catch` or similar in `Control.Exception` or wrappers around them